# "Checking for media presence" every boot

Tags: 14.04

Every time I boot my newly installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS my screen goes through a lengthy process of checking media presence, IP 4, IP 6 ... then nothing ... then it eventually loads about 10 minutes later. My last installation didn't do this. Is there something I need to change maybe?

Comment: something called GRUB is coming up

Comment: Please use the [edit] link below your posts, if you want to add something to them, instead of using the comment section for that.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the BIOS set via the F2 key...
Then when in the BIOS, go to the ADVANCED tap and look for "Network Stack"...
Click on "Network Stack", then if it's enabled... DISABLED it! Now save changes and exit...
That should do it...